# Constant accepted but not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I have the following question.

I have code like this:

```
'### CONSTANTS ###'
'**layer_dims** = [12288, 20, 7, 5, 1] #  4-layer model'

'def initialize_parameters_deep(**layer_dims**):
    """
    Arguments:
    layer_dims -- python array (list) containing the dimensions of each layer in our network

    Returns:
    parameters -- python dictionary containing your parameters "W1", "b1", ..., "WL", "bL":
                    Wl -- weight matrix of shape (layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1])
                    bl -- bias vector of shape (layer_dims[l], 1)
    """

    np.random.seed(1)
    parameters = {}
    L = len(layer_dims)            # number of layers in the network

    for l in range(1, L):
        parameters['W' + str(l)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1]) / np.sqrt(layer_dims[l-1]) #*0.01
        parameters['b' + str(l)] = np.zeros((layer_dims[l], 1))

        assert(parameters['W' + str(l)].shape == (layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1]))
        assert(parameters['b' + str(l)].shape == (layer_dims[l], 1))


    return parameters'
```

Now my question is, take a look at the bold `layer_dims`

It seems when I compile my code I have no error at all.
But the strange thing is when I put `layers_dim` (so layer with an s) in my function I receive also no error unthough the constant is defined as `layer_dims`

I start receiving an error when I put in the function eg: layerss_dim (2 ss), or blablabla or layer_dimsss etc...

The error is something like: `layerss_dim is not defined`.

So why do I not receive an error when I use my constant as `layers_dim` in my function and why do I receive an error when I use the above constants like layerss_dim, blablabla, layer_dimss, etc...

In any case the constant is defined as layer_dim!

Comment: When you write `def initialize_parameters_deep(layer_dims)`, this creates a "new" variable `layer_dims` which shadows the global variable (effectively, it replaces it within the function).

Comment: Also "when I compile my code": did you mean run? Python is (usually) interpreted.

Comment: Hoy Aimery, with compiling I mean run my cels (I use ipython). Ok I will come back later to this issue when I'm in the possibility to run my code again. I will take closer look when exactly I receive the error. For now as far as I remember, I do not get the error when I write eg: layers_dim, but well Layerss_dim. I do not exactly why in the one case error and in the other case not. As said I will rerun my code and take a closer look on how or when I fill in the different layer_dims and see when I get the error... thanks already for the answer.